# LINQ to Entities multiple columns need 1 to be distinct

Tags: linq

I am trying to select multiple columns from an entity object but I want 1 property to be distinct.  I am very new to both LINQ and Entity Framework so any help will be useful.

Here is my LINQ query so far:

```
var listTypes = (from s in context.LIST_OF_VALUES
                 orderby s.SORT_INDEX
                 select new { s.LIST_TYPE, s.DISPLAY_TEXT });
```

I want s.LIST_TYPE to be distinct.  I figure using the groupby keyword is what I want (maybe?) but I have not found a way to use it that works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `DISPLAY_TEXT` matches `LIST_TYPE` somehow (so you don't lose any information):

```
var distinct = context.LIST_OF_VALUES
    .OrderBy(s => s.SORT_INDEX)
    .GroupBy(s => s.LIST_TYPE)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, g.First().DISPLAY_TEXT });
```